# How are transmutation circles built?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

I've seen [Is each transmutation circle unique? (SciFi.SE)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27676) where the flame alchemy circle is explained.

Is there any rule to build the transmutation circles? Are there other symbols? What do squares, pentagons, pentagrams, hexagons, hexagrams, etc. mean?

Comment: Related (though not an answer): https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36805/how-important-is-transmutation-circle-pattern

Answer (score 1):

Almost every symbol, transmutation circle, and array in FmA;B have meanings behind them, even the ones who only appear on screen for a few seconds, like Riza's tattoo ([here's a link to a really good analysis of it](http://greed-the-dorkalicious.tumblr.com/post/145944671067/soterianyxs-analysis-and-interpretation-of-riza) and [here's a video where I talk a bit more about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv4GiaOwanw&t=72s)). All the gates shown also have personal meanings to the characters (I also talk about that a bit in the video). Most of the symbols are based on basic alchemy and I found out a lot of things by simply googeling "alchemy symbols"; so yes, I would say that it is totally possible to make your own circles by combining the diffrent symbols.